# How to add hyperlink to a poster image called from showOverlay()

Tags: jquery

What is the proper method to add a hyperlink on a poster image (video cover image - aka Thumb) that is called from a `showOverlay()` ?

The lack of adding a hyperlink to the image at the end of the video, the name of this image is poster_image_end.jpg - I have added text to this image for ease of understanding.  Text = poster Image End (this image needs to be clickable)

Link to jsfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/puqtrrd1/29/

```
<body>
<div id="mediaContainer" style="position: relative; width: 600px; height: 400px; overflow: hidden">
            <div id="videoContainer" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%">

     <!--  //  This is the Video  //  -->           
                <video id="video" src="http://jakursmu.com/action/videos/ios_overlay/5sec_vid.mp4" controls="controls" style="width: 100%; height: 100%" />
            </div>

     <!--  //  This is the Poster image #1 Start  //  -->
            <div id="overlay" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%; visibility: hidden; background-color: teal">
      <!--  //  This is the Poster image #1 Start  //  -->          
                <img id='overlay_image' src="http://jakursmu.com/action/videos/ios_overlay/poster_image_start.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%" />

  <!--  //  This is the Play button on Poster image #1  //  -->
      <div id="overlayElement" style="width: 75px; height: 75px; background-color: transparent; position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px"> <img src="http://jakursmu.com/action/videos/ios_overlay/play_button.png" width="110" height="109" alt="" /> 

                </div>
            </div>          
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var overlayShown = false;
var posterImages = { start: 'http://jakursmu.com/action/videos/ios_overlay/poster_image_start.jpg', end: 'http://jakursmu.com/action/videos/ios_overlay/poster_image_end.jpg' }
// Wherever you have showOverlay();, now do showOverlay( posterImages.start ); or
// showOverlay( posterImages.end );. You can also add more images to
// that list if you want
function showOverlay( imgSrc ) {
    // Hide video, show poster
    var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
    var imgElem = document.getElementById('overlay_image')
    imgElem.src = imgSrc;
    overlay.style.visibility = "visible";

    var videoContainer = document.getElementById("videoContainer");
    videoContainer.style.position = "absolute";
    videoContainer.style.top = "-2000px";
    overlayShown = true;
}

function hideOverlay() {
    // Hide poster, show video
    var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
    overlay.style.visibility = "hidden";
    var videoContainer = document.getElementById("videoContainer");
    videoContainer.style.position = "relative";
    videoContainer.style.top = "0px";
    overlayShown = false;
}

// init
(function() {
    var overlayElement = document.getElementById("overlayElement");
    overlayElement.onclick = function(e) {
        var el = e.target;
        el.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";/*  //  original color = Blue  //  */
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            // "Play" button clicked
            el.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";/*  //  original color = Green  //  */
            if ( overlayShown ) {
                hideOverlay();
                var videoElement = document.getElementById("video");
                videoElement.play();
            } else {

                showOverlay( posterImages.start );
            }
        }, 750);
    };

    var videoElement = document.getElementById("video");
    videoElement.addEventListener('pause', function() {
        // Paused, show poster
       showOverlay( posterImages.end );
    });
    videoElement.addEventListener('ended', function() {
        // Ended, try to close fullscreen if possible
        if (typeof videoElement.webkitExitFullscreen !== "undefined") {
            videoElement.webkitExitFullscreen();
        }
    });


    showOverlay( posterImages.start ); /*  //  The beginning of the script, this is the argument for the  Poster Image Start  //  */
})();</script>





</body>
```

Comment: try adding imgElem.addEventListener('click', YourFunction, false); in your showOverlay method and create a function YourFunction which will have the code that you want to execute when u click on the image at the end.

Comment: OK, Nice suggestion. I must not understand clearly your suggestion for my attempts did not produce the desired result. Can you provide an example in the jsfiddle demo?

Comment: i was trying to edit and save your jsfiddle but whenever i try to save it the whole thing clears out. let me try again

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/puqtrrd1/38/

Comment: Yes, Very close to perfection, now if I could find the location to add a link to be enacted with the click on image, it would be finished. Where is this located? Very cool what you have added!

Comment: check the DoSomething() method. it has the alert in it. just replace it with whatever u want.

Comment: Oh Yes, I have been doing exactly this, my format must be incorrect, for is breaks the script. View here my mistake. http://jsfiddle.net/puqtrrd1/40/

Comment: replace ('http://jakursmu.com/action/') with this window.location = 'http://jakursmu.com/action/' ;

Comment: Yes, Yes... you have effortlessly solved my 2 day battle. I wish I know how you were I would give you a gift certificate for two. Thanks you for this kind help!!

Comment: you're most welcome :) let me post this as an answer. please mark it as an answer.

Comment: i've posted my solution as an answer @Alex. please mark it as an answer and if it helped, please upvote it. glad my solution helped.

Comment: if you see my answer below, it will have a mark as answer/ solution button below it and it has an up and down arrow. just click the up arrow and click on the mark as answer button. you can read this for more info on how to accept one's answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Comment: I sure will, this is my first time here, if you will kindly point me in the correct area to do this request, I would be happy to do this for you. I

Comment: please refer the link http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow . it is easy. m looking at your live example and trying to figure out why its not showing the images.

Comment: i can see the images on the live site now. for accepting answer refer this image, http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-answers-accepted.png also this link http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: the live example error ... look at the last line of the script, i had double })(); I removed them and reloaded the page. I will follow your link to get you a up arrow.

Comment: yeah i saw that. was going to tell u, but u figured it out.

Comment: Thank You, reading your link to vote. So far, it appears I do not qualify to vote? I have been able to get you pushed up by clicking on the check mark and turning it to a green color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you basically need to add an eventlistener on the dynamic element that you're creating which in this case is the image at the end of the video.

try adding `imgElem.addEventListener('click', DoSomething, false);` in the `showOverlay` method. DoSomething can have the code to redirect to another page on your site.

```
function DoSomething(){
    window.location.href = 'www.google.com';
}
```

and update your showOverlay method to accept a flag which says if the video has ended.

```
function showOverlay( imgSrc, isEnded ) {
    // Hide video, show poster
    var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
    var imgElem = document.getElementById('overlay_image')
    imgElem.src = imgSrc;
    overlay.style.visibility = "visible";

    if(typeof isEnded != 'undefined' && isEnded == true){
        imgElem.addEventListener('click', DoSomething, false);
    }

    var videoContainer = document.getElementById("videoContainer");
    videoContainer.style.position = "absolute";
    videoContainer.style.top = "-2000px";
    overlayShown = true;
}
```

and when you're calling the method, pass the additional flag

```
showOverlay( posterImages.end, true );
```

here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/puqtrrd1/38/

Answer (score 0):

Typically links are `<a>` elements. So why not change `img#overlay_image` to be a link that *contains* the image element? Then you can use JS or Jquery to update the `<a>` element's `href` attribute whenever you'd like. (Or, if it will always link to the same place, just populate the `href` when the page loads initially.)

Perhaps something like this: (adjust your CSS accordingly)

```
<a href="" id="overlay_image_wrap">
  <img src="http://jakursmu.com/action/videos/ios_overlay/poster_image_end.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
</a>

...

// in your Jquery code whenever you're ready
var special_url = "/some/special/url.php"
$('#overlay_image_wrap').attr('href', special_url);
```

Comment: Let me attempt your suggestion. Im new to java, Im 57 so this is a brain test for me. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, your advise is over my pay scale, I mess it up. Can you add the code to th jsfiddle? Put any link on the last image, I can see how you did it.